# Regex or Linq to capture the key and value pair in c#

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a string like  below

Loop="start:yes " while=" end" do=" yes "

**expected string**
Loop="start:yes" while="end" do="Yes"

I tried to capture the key and value pair(ex. Loop="start:yes ") and remove the white space in each pair and then concatenate whole string as expected string above

```
        //string rx = "([\\w+\\s]*\\=?[\\s]*\\\"[\\w+\\s]*\\\")";

        string rx = ".+?\\=?[\\s]*\\\".+?\\\"";

        Console.WriteLine(rx);
        Match m = Regex.Match(tempString, rx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (m.Success)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);    
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);   
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);   
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[4].Value);

        }
```

Tried above code but am unable to capture any pair in the string

Comment: what happened then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback method to the `Regex.Replace`, and inside that method, populate an object of `Dictionary<string, string>`.

You can use the [following regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Ckey%3E%5Cw%2B)%3D%22%5Cs*(%3F%3Cval%3E.*%3F)%5Cs*%22&i=Loop%3D%22start%3Ayes%20%22%20while%3D%22%20end%22%20do%3D%22%20yes%20%22&r=) to grab the keys and values:

```
(?<key>\w+)="\s*(?<val>.*?)\s*"
```

The regex matches:

- `(?<key>\w+)` - matches and stores in a capture group names*key* 1 or more alphanumeric symbols or underscore
- `="` - a literal `="`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `(?<val>.*?)` - matches and captures into group names *val* any number of any characters but a newline as few as possible before the closest...
- `\s*"` - 0 or more whitespace symbols followed by a `"`.

Here is the C# demo:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private string callbck(Match m)
{
    dct.Add(m.Groups["key"].Value, m.Groups["val"].Value);
    return string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", m.Groups["key"].Value, m.Groups["val"].Value);
}
```

And this is the main code:

```
var s = "Loop=\"start:yes \" while=\" end\" do=\" yes \"";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<key>\w+)=""\s*(?<val>.*?)\s*""",  callbck);
```

Result: `Loop="start:yes" while="end" do="yes"`,

[image]